# Facing a issue on client calling REST API of server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am facing a issue on calling REST API in following scenarios

1. There are two web application webappA(client), webappB(server)
2. Client webappA calling API of webappB(server)
3. If client webappA calling API and if the server application webappB has no such API(in case of previous build/war, before implementing API), then spring redirecting it to login page and then client is receiving response of API as login page as string( e.g. `str = < html>.....< /htm>`)

Rest client code (webappA) :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate().getForObject(serverUrl, String.class);
```

Server code(webappB) : Note that this code will not existin in old build/war/version of webappB

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz.htm")
public ResponseEntity<String> apiMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    return (new ResponseEntity<String>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

How I can solve this issue, instead of getting response string as login page (e.g. `str = "< html>.........< /htm>"`). I need something from spring where rest client webappA can identify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A JSON response from webappB would be fine?? Asking for giving the solution.

Comment: But there is no API in webappB, this is with the case of old build. Say webappB-1.0.0. (and API is  implemented later e.g. in webappB-5.0.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to get a JSON response from webappB if no handler found for a particular URL requested by webappA:

Edit your web.xml as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/location/of/servlet_context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Now write a ExceptionHanler in your Controller or GlobalExceptionHandler class

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<JSONReturned> exception(NoHandlerFoundException exception){

    ResponseEntity<JSONReturned> responseEntity = null;
    JSONReturned jsonReturned = new JSONReturned();
    jsonReturned.setMsg("Sorry your request cannot be completed.");
    jsonReturned.setResponse("Requested URL is not present.");
    responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<JSONReturned>(jsonReturned, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

JSONReturned is a simple POJO class for carrying the message:

```
    public class JSONReturned {

    private String msg;
    private String response;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I think, it will change existing implementation of redirecting to login page of webappB

Comment: In fact we cann't change the old build/war/versions of webappB, need to handle at client end

Comment: If you are not able to change the existing content, then do the following: 1) Send a REST request. 2) When you getting response search for some particular thing which is present on the login page only. You can do this using Jsoup.

Comment: While searching dont parse whole response page but just one particular attribute you are sure about. And if you find that particular attribute you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Will this help depending on your requirement ??

Comment: Currently I did same, as temp solution, but its kind of static/hardcode. So looking for generic solution. But as of now it seems, for generic solution I need to update server side API. Thanks for your help/time.

Comment: I have updated API to return object instead of string e.g. JSONReturned. Thank you

Comment: Good choice. Now you will be able to do many more things. Like handling any exception you want and return a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 404 from the REST API since the path is not existing yet. You can change your default 404 response in your server (webappB) to what ever you prefer. https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Comment: Thanks for response, all unknown request is redirected to login page and in this case existing implementation will change.

Comment: In fact we cann't change the old build/war/versions of webappB, need to handle at client end